# font path problem in adding text over image in php

Tags: php

Everything is fine with below code to add text over image except font_path.

```
<?php
  //Set the Content Type
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

  // Create Image From Existing File
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('sunset.jpg');

  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);

  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'arial.TTF';

  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = "This is a sunset!";

  // Print Text On Image
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);

  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image);

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

i tried

```
$font_path = 'arial.TTF';
$font_path = '/arial.TTF';
$font_path = './arial.TTF';
$font_path = '../arial.TTF';
```

and many other. and i put arial.ttf in all folder of script. it works with only with this src:

```
$font_path = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\app\arial.TTF';
```

and of course this path is not suitable for my website.

How can i fix that? or do you have any better solution to add text over image in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like below.

```
// When the font file is in the same directry as your php file
$font_path = __DIR__ . '/arial.TTF';

// When the font file is in the parent directry of your php file
$font_path = dirname(__DIR__) . '/arial.TTF'
```